# Toolbar to follow up after the keyboard appears in Material

Tags: android-layout, meteor, html-framework-7

how to make the toolbar remains at the bottom, do not go up on top after the keyboard appears ??
what's wrong with my code or less some plugins for cordova or framework7! maybe someone can help me to solve this problem.

```html
<div class="views">
    <div class="view">
      <div class="pages">
    <div data-page="viewprofil" class="page navbar-fixed toolbar-fixed">
      <div class="navbar" style="background-color: #1abc9c;box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.1), 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);">
          <div class="navbar-inner" >
              <div id="kembali" class="left sliding button">
                <i class="icon icon-back"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="left sliding">Akun</div>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="toolbar toolbar-bottom">
        <div class="toolbar-inner">
            <a id="kembali">
                <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="{{pathFor 'history'}}" >
                <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
            <a href="{{pathFor 'viewprofil'}}" class="toolbar-aktif">
                <i class="fa fa-user fa-2x"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
      </div>

  <div class="page-content" style="background-color: #ecf0f1;color: #444444;">
    <div class="content-block-title" style="top: 0px; margin-top:0px;"><h2>Pengaturan Akun</h2></div>
    <div class="list-block">
      <ul class="box-data">
        <li>
          <div class="item-content">
            <div class="item-media"><i class="icon material-icons">person</i></div>
            <div class="item-inner">

              <div class="item-input">
                <input id="namalengkap" type="text" placeholder="Nama lengkap" value="{{nama}}">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="item-content">
            <div class="item-media"><i class="icon material-icons">email</i></div>
            <div class="item-inner">

              <div class="item-input">
                <input type="text" value="{{email}}" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <li class="accordion-item">
            <a class="item-content item-link">
              <div class="item-media"><i class="icon material-icons" aria-hidden="true">lock</i></div>
              <div class="item-inner">
                <div class="item-title">Kata Sandi</div>
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="accordion-item-content">
              <div class="content-block" style="margin-left: 80px;">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Kata Sandi baru">
              </div>
              <div class="content-block" style="margin-left: 80px;">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Ulangi Kata Sandi">
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </li>

        <li>
          <div class="item-content">
            <div class="item-media"><i class="icon material-icons">call</i></div>
            <div class="item-inner">
              <div class="item-input">
                <input type="tel" placeholder="No. Handphone" value="{{notelp}}">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <div class="content-block">
        <div class="logButton button button-fill button-raised color-red" id="logout" ><i class="fa fa-power-off " aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Keluar</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0xEf.jpg)

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koxAp.jpg)

Comment: Please share some code from your current implementation. Also let us know what you've attempted so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never came out of an idea to keep it in the bottom, but here is a quick fix:

```
var myApp = new Framework7({
    material: true
});

var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
});

$$ = Dom7;

$$('#my-input').on('focus', function() {
   mainView.hideToolbar();
});

$$('#my-input').on('blur', function() {
  mainView.showToolbar();
});
```

Simply show and hide the toolbar on input focus and blur events.

Live Example: https://jsfiddle.net/wowq3n64/